# How to restrict access to job groups in Rundeck for different users?

Tags: rundeck

I have a Rundeck Project where I have multiple jobs categorised into groups.

```
Like this
  Project_Admin
    |
     configure
    |         |_job_1
    |
     administrator
              |_job_2
```

Now I have users who are categorized as admin and users.

I want

"admin" group to access to "configure" and "administrator"  jobs with create/read/run/kill privileges

and

"users" group to access to "configure" and "administrator" jobs with read/run privileges

My confusion is in admin.aclpolicy how do I mark groups for jobs?

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for the users you have to create the users.aclpolicy file and restrict their access in that file while the admins will use the admins.aclpolicy settings.